# JPA merge/persist

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa-2.0

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
A.class
B.class
C.class
D.class
```

`A.class` contém muitas `B.class` que contém uma `D.class`

`C.class` contém muitas `D.class` que contém uma `B.class`

Sendo que `D.class` é persistida em `CascadeType.Persist` quando `C.class` for persistida.

Cenário: busco uma `C.class` faço uma atualização de um atributo da classe, por exemplo, somar o numero sequencial e insiro uma `D.class` que será persistido em cascata. Para cada operação de atualização realizada, uma `D.class` é inserida, semelhante a um log.
Para realizar essa situação eu chamo o método merge (`C.class`) que atualiza a `C.class` e também persiste uma `D.class`.

Porém, quando eu faço essa operação anterior, eu preciso realizar uma criação da `A.class` na mesma transação, sendo assim faço uma inserção de uma `A.class` que contém pelo menos uma `B.class` que tem relação para a minha `D.class` que foi inserida em cascata na situação anterior.
Ocorre o seguinte problema quando faço `EntityManager.persist(A.class)`:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : br.com.criabyte.model.aplicacao.financeiro.cxa.FinCxaPlanoLcto.finCprParcelaLcto -> br.com.criabyte.model.aplicacao.financeiro.cpr.FinCprParcelaLcto
```

Ou seja, a relação não conseguiu encontrar aquele objeto anteriormente persistido em cascata.
`FinCxaPlanoLcto` é a `B.class` que contém uma `FinCprParcelaLcto` que é o objeto de `D.class`.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que poderia estar fazendo para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema com a seguinte situação, quando fiz o merge() recuperei o objeto e atualizei ele novamente.